# LinQ to objects. Сортировать List<objects[]>

Tags: c#, сортировка, list, linq

`List<objects[]>` представляет собой список значений для таблицы.

к примеру, содержит следующее:

```
myList.Add(new object[] { "column_1", "column_2" });
myList.Add(new object[] { "Вася", "4" });
myList.Add(new object[] { "Оля", "6" });
myList.Add(new object[] { "Дима", "2" });
```

Как отсортировать по одному из столбцов?
Запись ниже результата не даёт.

```
IEnumerable<object[]> myListSorted = myList.OrderBy(i => myList[0].Length);
```

Только начинаю работать с LinQ, буду благодарен любой подсказке.

Comment: Не используйте `object[]`, используйте нормальные классы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сортировка по первому элементу массивов в списке:

```
IEnumerable<object[]> myListSorted = myList.OrderBy(i => i[0]);
```

Сортировка по второму элементу массивов в списке:

```
IEnumerable<object[]> myListSorted = myList.OrderBy(i => i[1]);
```